# Trying to find a correlation in data from 2 sensors

Tags: numerical-analysis

I've been trying to find a way to correlate data sets from two sensor types. In theory these measure the same signal. One is in a known format expressed in meters while the other is in numeric form read from a 24 bit value. If anyone could help me find a way to find the approximate meter value of these integer values I would be so appreciative for the assistance.

These sensors may have different offsets but the difference between each set of two measurements should be close. I am listing the known values first then the integer representation from the unknown sensor.

Sample 1

0.3940 meters = 38884

0.3860 meters = -348332

Sample 2

0.2125 meters = 32230

0.2055 meters = -97977

Sample 3

0.6510 meters = 21108

0.7495 meters = -363721

I have many more sample sets. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried simple conversions. Such as decimal multiplication, 1e-5, 2e-5, xe-6, ect, various powers of 2, 2^20, 2^21, ect. I even tried looking at small fractions of the carrier frequency wavelengths. The data pairs each are measured from a different source and compare 2 carrier frequencies. Sometimes I think I have a conversion that works for 1 source but it doesn't work for any others. I'm at a loss :(

Comment: @JosieH When I plot out the meter values associated with their integer representation, there isn't a linear model to go from integer representation to measurement in meters. This means it isn't really a surprise your attempt to find a multiplication factor isn't working. I think you're going to have to consider using a lot more samples and building some statistical model. If you could plot the various measurements, it might be easier to help.

Comment: It's possible that the integer values that you are seeing are binary numbers in which the order of bytes has been swapped in some way.  You could try the various permutations of the byte order to see if any of them make sense.